# Typescript not reading data from .env file

Tags: javascript, typescript, database, string, mongodb

I am trying to get my typescipt config file to read data from .env file but ${string} is not being read here.

```
const MONGO_URL='mongodb+srv://${MONGO_USERNAME}:${MONGO_PASSWORD}@cluster0.r25lk3v.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
```

Comment: You should access environment variables with `process.env.MONGO_USERNAME` and `process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD` unless you have deconstructed the two attributes on previous lines

Comment: Can you share the error statement?

Comment: Are you using `dotenv`? If so, please show the relevant code. If not, where are `MONGO_USERNAME` and `MONGO_PASSWORD` supposed to come from?

Comment: The problem was with Auth of the user for the DB.
Initially it was set as X.509 which when changed to SCRAM it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `` instead of single quotes.

```
const MONGO_URL=`mongodb+srv://${MONGO_USERNAME}:${MONGO_PASSWORD}@cluster0.r25lk3v.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
```